# iferror equivalent in R

Tags: r

Here is the simplified version:

Suppose I am using 'which' function to find a position, say -

```
position_num=which(df$word=="ABC")
```

If the value exists it is fine and it returns an integer, but in case it is unable to match it returns `integer(0)` in such a case I want to assign a default value to position_num=1.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Sounds like you want `tryCatch` to me.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, can you please help me with a short example code how we can solve this with tryCatch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like the following `if()` statement would probably do it.

```
position_num = if(!length(w <- which(df$word == "ABC"))) 1 else w
```

Here we are just checking to see if the result from `which()` has a length, because

```
length(integer(0))
# [1] 0
```

And we return 1 if it doesn't have a length, and the `which()` result (`w`) otherwise.

Comment: This one is much better than mine, because:

1. It does not call ifelse, which can be time consuming
2. It calls which() only once

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
position_num=ifelse(length(which(df$word=="ABC")) != 0,which(df$word=="ABC"),1)
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel for the assistance